# Problema con patrón regex (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

Me gustaría poder encontrar todos estos "handlebars" que tengo en un string.

**Ejemplo de string**

```
Hola a todos mi nombre es {{name,uppercase}} tengo {{age}}.
```

Básicamente lo que necesito es encontrar absolutamente todos los {{ }} que hayan en el documento y **solamente** obtener lo que hay adentro. Es decir que en el ejemplo que di, debería devolverme que se encontró: `name,uppercase` y `age`.

Estoy usando el siguiente patrón `{{(.*?)}}` pero parece no funcionar por que me devuelve el siguiente array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {{name} ) [1] => Array ( [0] => {name ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {{name} ) [1] => Array ( [0] => {name ) )
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El carácter { lo tienes que poner como \{ de lo contrario regex lo interpreta como número de repeticiones. Ej. \d{3} significa 3 digitos para regex. En tu caso puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
    <?php
        $re = '/(?>\{\{([^{]*)\}\})/m';
        $str = 'Hola a todos mi nombre es {{name,uppercase}} tengo {{age}}.';
        preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);
        var_dump($matches[1]);

    ?>
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(14) "name,uppercase"
  [1]=> string(3) "age"
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Ahora funciona.

Comment: Un gusto saber que pude ayudarte.